# Pushing & Popping a frame to a Mat vector

Tags: c++, vector, opencv3.0

I am trying to grab multiple frames from 2 USB cameras using threads. Issue is i need to push frames into frame_queue vector and then pop one frame at a time from the vector for further image processing.
I followed this link 
https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/05/29/multi-thread-multi-camera-capture-using-opencv/

The code in this link has used concurrent_queue.h for queuing up Mat frames but instead i want to use vector Mat to store the incoming frames.

Header file CameraStreamer.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
//#include <concurrent_queue.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//using namespace concurrency;

class CameraStreamer{
public:
//this holds camera stream urls
vector<string> camera_source;
//this holds usb camera indices
vector<int> camera_index;
//this holds OpenCV VideoCapture pointers
vector<VideoCapture*> camera_capture;
//this holds queue(s) which hold images from each camera
vector<Mat*> frame_queue;
//this holds thread(s) which run the camera capture process
vector<thread*> camera_thread;

//Constructor for IP Camera capture
CameraStreamer(vector<string> source);
//Constructor for USB Camera capture
CameraStreamer(vector<int> index);
//Destructor for releasing resource(s)
~CameraStreamer();

private:
   bool isUSBCamera;
   int camera_count;
   //initialize and start the camera capturing process(es)
   void startMultiCapture();
   //release all camera capture resource(s)
   void stopMultiCapture();
   //main camera capturing process which will be done by the thread(s)
   void captureFrame(int index);
   };
```

Here is my CameraStreamer.cpp:

```
#include "camerastreamer.h"

CameraStreamer::CameraStreamer(vector<string> stream_source)
{
camera_source = stream_source;
camera_count = camera_source.size();
isUSBCamera = false;

startMultiCapture();
}

CameraStreamer::CameraStreamer(vector<int> capture_index)
{
camera_index = capture_index;
camera_count = capture_index.size();
isUSBCamera = true;

startMultiCapture();
}

CameraStreamer::~CameraStreamer()
{
stopMultiCapture();
}

void CameraStreamer::captureFrame(int index)
{
VideoCapture *capture = camera_capture[index];
while (true)
{
    Mat frame;
    //Grab frame from camera capture
    (*capture) >> frame;
    //Put frame to the queue
    frame_queue[index]->push(frame);
    //relase frame resource
    frame.release();
}
}

void CameraStreamer::startMultiCapture()
{
VideoCapture *capture;
thread *t;
vector<Mat> *q;
for (int i = 0; i < camera_count; i++)
{
    //Make VideoCapture instance
    if (!isUSBCamera){
    string url = camera_source[i];
            capture = new VideoCapture(url);
            cout << "Camera Setup: " << url << endl;
        }
        else{
            int idx = camera_index[i];
            capture = new VideoCapture(idx);
            cout << "Camera Setup: " << to_string(idx) << endl;
        }

        //Put VideoCapture to the vector
        camera_capture.push_back(capture);

        //Make thread instance
        t = new thread(&CameraStreamer::captureFrame, this, i);

        //Put thread to the vector
        camera_thread.push_back(t);

        //Make a queue instance
        q = new vector<Mat>;

        //Put queue to the vector
        frame_queue.push_back(q);
    }
}

void CameraStreamer::stopMultiCapture()
{
    VideoCapture *cap;
    for (int i = 0; i < camera_count; i++)
    {
        cap = camera_capture[i];
        if (cap->isOpened()){
            //Relase VideoCapture resource
            cap->release();
            cout << "Capture " << i << " released" << endl;
        }
    }
    }
```

Main.cpp:

```
int main()
{

//IP camera URLs
vector<string> capture_source = {
    "rtsp://192.168.2.100/profile2/media.smp",
    "rtsp://192.168.0.100/profile2/media.smp"
};

//USB Camera indices
vector<int> capture_index = { 0, 1 };

//Highgui window titles
vector<string> label;
for (size_t i = 0; i < capture_index.size(); i++)
{
    string title = "CCTV " + to_string(i);
    label.push_back(title);
}

//Make an instance of CameraStreamer
CameraStreamer cam(capture_index);

while (waitKey(20) != 27)
{
    //Retrieve frames from each camera capture thread
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capture_index.size(); i++)
    {
        Mat *frame;
        //Pop frame from queue and check if the frame is valid
        cam.frame_queue[i].pushback(frame);
        //Show frame on Highgui window
            imshow(label[i], frame);
        }
    }
 }
```

i tried using

```
cam.frame_queue[i].pushback(frame);
```

but it doesn't work.

So i am not sure how do i push and pop a frame into frame_queue vector with an index.

Comment: I don't know what a `CameraStreamer::frame_queue` is.

Comment: please follow the link in the question for the whole code.

Comment: Oh thanks that's convenient.

Comment: "Here i have a Mat vector frame_queue". Doesn't seem like you have a `std::vector<Mat>`.

Comment: Since i am using vector<Mat*> it throws an error cv::Mat has no member named try_pop. I guess its a member of concurrency but i am not using it.

Comment: Could you post the actual code you're having problems with? You obviously have different code from the one on that website you posted.

Comment: OK i will post the total code.

Comment: Please post the complete portion of the code you are having problems with. This involves narrowing down the scope of the code that is causing the problem. Better yet, try posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105439/discussion-between-marks-and-nard).